# Get text between two tags

Tags: php, preg-match

How can I get the value from the following tags:

```
{desc=1}
This is a description
{/desc}
```

The number in the `{desc=1}` is changing. I want to get the value as well.

UPDATED:

also possible to be more `desc` in the string, for example

```
{desc=1}
    This is a description
{/desc} 
{desc=2}
    other description
{/desc}
...
```

Comment: You should use XML. It would make everything easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will capture everything you want.

```
$data = <<<EOT
{desc=1}
    This is a description
{/desc}
{desc=2}
    other description
{/desc}
EOT;

preg_match_all('#{desc=(\d+)}(.*?){/desc}#s', $data, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(44) "{desc=1}
    This is a description
{/desc}"
    [1]=>
    string(40) "{desc=2}
    other description
{/desc}"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(29) "
    This is a description
"
    [1]=>
    string(25) "
    other description
"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have only one question, what is the # in the begging and #s in the end?

Comment: @iUngi, PHP allows you to use several different characters to escape a regex (other than `/`). I used it so that I wouldn't have to escape `/` with `\/` if I had to use them literally.

Answer (score 1):

Another very simple way is we can create a simple function that can be invoked at any time.

```
<?php
  // Create the Function to get the string
  function GetStringBetween ($string, $start, $finish) {
  $string = " ".$string;
  $position = strpos($string, $start);
  if ($position == 0) return "";
  $position += strlen($start);
  $length = strpos($string, $finish, $position) - $position;
  return substr($string, $position, $length);
  }
?>
```

and here's an example usage for your question

```
$string1="
{desc=1}
 This is a description
{/desc}";

$string2="
{desc=1}
 This is a description
{/desc}
{desc=2}
  other description
{/desc}";

echo GetStringBetween ($string1, "{desc=1}", "{/desc}");
echo GetStringBetween ($string2, "{desc=1}", "{/desc}");
echo GetStringBetween ($string2, "{desc=2}", "{/desc}");
```

For more detail please read http://codetutorial.com/howto/how-to-get-of-everything-string-between-two-tag-or-two-strings.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function getInbetweenStrings($start, $end, $str){
    $matches = array();
    $regex = "/$start([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$end/";
    preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

$str = "{attr1}/{attr2}/{attr3}";
$str_arr = getInbetweenStrings('{', '}', $str);

print_r($str_arr);
```

in above example { and } are the tags, in-between them the string is getting extracted.