# Extract text from multiple HTML tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, text-extraction

I am trying to make this work but I can't:

```
$str = "<html>1</html><html>2</html><html>3</html>";
$matches = array(); 
preg_match_all("(?<=<html>)(.*?)(?=</html>)", $str, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $d)
{
   echo $d;
}
```

What I am doing wrong? The output must be:

```
123
```

Comment: If all you want is to grab number wouldn’t be easier to do just `preg_match_all('\d')`

Comment: This is not really about parsing `HTML/XML`

Comment: You could have copied you code to: https://regex101.com/r/parpaL/1, and look at the explanation why you did get an error....    (HINT:  The error shown is `/ An unescaped delimiter must be escaped; in most languages with a backslash (\)`

Comment: It isn't just a regex issue, OP already had a good regex. There were other issues mentioned in my answer.

Comment: The fact that the asked question is a snowflake does not mean that the question has not been asked before.  How to extract text from between an html tag has been asked many times.  I know this.  Anyone with >700k knows this.  Anyone who has read regex questions here for a minimum of a year know this.  It is the same as: how can I sort an array? It doesn't matter how snowflakey it is ...it is a duplicate.  Answering these questions by high reppers is farming.

Comment: Dupes (including dupes which have dupes): [get everything between <tag> and </tag> with php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9253027/2943403) and [Php get string between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25817248/2943403) and [PHP Regex find text between custom added HTML Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602251/2943403) and [PHP get string between tag [Multiple tag in one string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35168463/2943403) and [Get text between two tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6559067/2943403)

Comment: [Best way to match text between tags with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40609710/2943403) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148592/how-to-find-and-replace-string-between-two-tags-using-regex-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39148592/2943403) and [Get text between HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5699911/2943403)

Comment: Even back in 2011, a knowledgeable contributor stated that [there are a hundred instances of this {judgment} question being asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699911/get-text-between-html-tags#comment6514786_5699911).  The sane thing to ask oneself is: Would the asker have even asked the question if they would have read the duplicate? When it is reasonable that the new question would have been prevented STOP SENSELESSLY UNHAMMERING DUPLICATES.

Comment: Stop reopening bad questions that are close-worthy. You are hurting the site, and people’s ability to find questions similar to theirs, and their chances of resolving their problems without having to ask a question themselves. Do everyone a favour, and stop hurting this valuable curation of the site.

Comment: A detailed explanation is of immediate help to the author; you are not helping them figure out their problems by themselves, and the question is not helpful to anybody else. You’re helping polluting the site with an endless amount of very similar questions, yet different, and none about exactly what anybody needs later. You’re destroying the chances of discovering the knowledge that’ll make people able to quickly solve their own problems!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```php
$str = "<html>1</html><html>2</html><html>3</html>";
preg_match_all("~(?<=<html>).*?(?=</html>)~", $str, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $d) {
   echo $d;
}
```

**Output:**

```
123
```

**Changes are:**

- Use missing regex delimiters `~` in `preg_match_all` function pattern
- Remove capturing group since you are already using lookahead and lookbehind so entire match can be used in further processing
- Using `$matches[0]` in `foreach` loop instead of `$matches`
- There is no need to declare/initialize `$matches` before `preg_match_all` call

Answer (score 0):

You need to add delimiters (I've used `!`) and you can skip the lookaheads/lookbehinds. Just make a capture group around the numbers you want. Nothing else.
Then look in the second `matches` element for the array with the individual values.

Example:

```php
preg_match_all("!<html>(.*?)</html>!", $str, $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $d)
{
   echo $d;
}
```